# custom wiki page layout with forms

Tags: custom

(rookie question ... just getting started with Sharepoint)

Is it possible to create a custom page layout for a wiki page which contains form elements?

Basically, I want to create a site that will host wiki pages, with associated features like rating, comments etc. But I want the wiki content to be structured somewhat. There need to be form elements like select boxes, radio buttons - and then a free form wiki area that would be composed using the WYSIWYG editor.

How would I go about doing this? Where should I look for documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  You need to create a custom content type first that contains the fields you need then you create a custom page layout based on that content type - you can copy the wiki page layout as a start point - then add in the custom fields.